# iOS Swift Spotify SDK Auth unknown error occured

Tags: swift, authentication, sdk, access-token, spotify

I really have no idea more. I read Spotify guide, I read various articles, I watched videos on YouTube, I even launched other people’s projects - authorization fails everywhere. Spotify opens, shows "X" and then in the logs I see "An unknown error has occurred"

I tried logging in like this:

```
appRemote.authorizeAndPlayURI("")
// I also tried this
sessionManager.initiateSession(with: scopes, options: .clientOnly)
```

but the result is the same everywhere

my `info.plist` is correct and Spotify Dashboard App is configured correctly (bundle ID and Redirect URI are correct)

```
info.plist

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>spotify</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.blaBlaBla.blaBlaBla</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>blaBlaBla</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Where is my mistake and how i can fix that? Thank you for any suggest

**UPDATE:** I also added my Spotify account to users list for auth in development mode. But still no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found a solution

in the **Spotify Dashboard** when you setup ur app you should add `Redirect URIs`

and all `URIs` should be end with `/` sign. For ex:

```
myAppName://auth-login-callback/
myAppName://some-action-callback/
```